# Rainbow kit connect wallet not working Properly

Tags: reactjs, metamask, react-rainbow-components

After logging in the first time, the connect wallet gets connected, but it is not working once I disconnect and click on connect wallet button. For some reason, openConnectModal is giving undefined. But once I refresh the page and then click on connect wallet, is working fine.
Steps to replicate:

1. Login into the account
   2.Click on Connect wallet
2. Once connected, disconnect the metamask wallet.
3. Click on connect wallet again. (Here is the issue, it is not getting connected)
   issue.

"wagmi": "^0.12.10","@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^0.12.7",

@wagmi-dev ## @rainbow-me

1. login account
2. Connect metamask wallet
3. disconnect metamask wallet
4. Click on connect wallet and metamask wallet gets connected.